# Verifying Youtube Video in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

We have a need to verify content on our site using Selenium IDE; specifically for this question Youtube video served up in an iframe:

```
{<iframe width="506" height="315" frameborder="0" class="player" id="player" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9l1WYPhs0cc?wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.com"></iframe>}
```

(origin xed out...)

I have tried to use Selenium to click on the video - no result, and running through a list I knew a video was not available - it went right through it, so that doesn't work for verification.  I settled down to a storeEval statement and attempted to do the getElementById javascript statement, but that really can't find the element that is loaded by the iframe.

Anybody had to verify Youtube content?

Answer (score 2):

In my browser, the YouTube iframe embeds a Flash player.  Ordinarily, Selenium can't talk to embedded components, but [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html) talks about using the [FlashSelenium](https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) component to talk to Flash.